# Why in different places seems directions are changed?

Tags: earth-rotation, earth-system

I'm living at place **A** I traveled to **B** and I seen like sun isn't set as in place **A**. Like directions are changed. Where **east** is in place **B** is **north** of **A** and **south** of **A** is   **west** of **B**. Because of sun wasn't set in **B** as usually as set in place **A**. Sun rises in north at place **B** and sets in south. I really confused with this phenomenon of nature. Is it mean we consider direction which region we living in? Is it all because of *longitude* and *latitude*? Why it'd be like this? May it because if sun travel by specific longitude and latitude and so we would confused in situation like this even sun is stable planet and just earth rotate?

Comment: almost everywere on the planet the sun rises in the east and sets in the west,atleast twice a year. it might be interesting to see what direction the answers to this whill take.

Comment: You have to tell us the places and times and the exact directions - if only to show us that this is not a case of bad observations.

Comment: what i think is the question is this,when i travel north/south why do the sun  not rise/set in the direct east/west direction but  moves notrh/south.if this is the case it is a question better asked in the astronomy section,it is possible i am wrong but it sounds like it fits better over there.

Comment: Places are town (Hometown) Mohol- Dist. Solapur, Maharshtra - India 17.8100° N, 75.6432° E. and other (traveled to) village near from Solapur traveled at north and seen these differences 17.8046° N, 75.8962° E. Some other places I don't found something like this.

Comment: Just in case one of these places is subject to a localized magnetic anomaly, is your ascertaining of east & west based on readings from a compass, or just observation of the sun in the sky?

Comment: Just observed sun in the sky.

Comment: There's only a 0.6 km difference in the north-south distance between those two points. That's far too small too see any distinction in the direction of sunrise and sunset with the eye.

Comment: Even I observed shadows and directions but I seen differences. I found same thing at 16.7050° N, 74.2433° E but not here 18.5204° N, 73.8567° E.   So I wonder it'd be with this little far distance.

Comment: I think the general consensus is: they couldn't be noticeably different directions.  But perhaps something made you mistake your directions, so you weren't looking in the direction you thought you were (compass was bad, road/house designs, etc).  I've certainly been mislead by those kinds of things before.

Comment: I really don'y know why it because and confused. But I want to know why, want to find reason. Sun changes directions but I think it wouldn't affect this little far distance.

Comment: @Fred Question has answered and commented so if want to more clear asking then please edit.

Answer (score 1):

Even though sun always moves from east to west, latitude affects the north-south perception.
If you are in the north hemisphere, beyond the tropic of cancer, the sun will be most of the time in the south hemisphere (except close to dawn and dusk, where it might cross to the other hemisphere during summer). While if you're in the south hemisphere, beyond the tropic of capricorn, the sun will be at north.
Usually I use the sun to check where is the north in a map, but I must remember the north-south rule, otherwise I might choose the wrong direction to follow... that's why a bougth a cheap compass.

Since you're talking about two places that are in the tropical belt, most part of the year the sun will rise in the north-east, move later to the south and it will end in the north-west. But during the winter the sun probably will be always in the south hemisphere.

Probably the difference they are seeing between two close towns is due to different times of the year or due to a mountain that covers the exact sunset in the horizon in one place.

Comment: Time was same I mean day. I didn't visit in different season and wasn't mountains in this place. And I seen clear sunset. Even I seen different since my childhood though. But even if sun changing direction as you explained   is it expected in this little far distance?

Comment: @Swapnil - The distance is too small, both places should see almost same behaivour of the sun. One of your observations should be wrong. Try to get a compass to confirm.

Comment: Okay I'll try. I had tried if there's compass available onilne.